# Graph QL not returning me the correct data

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I am trying to run a graph ql query to get the details of some jobs.

The query is something like this:

```
query getJobsSearch(
$location: String
$type: String
$category: String
$time: String
$limit: Int
) {

jobs(order_by: {created_at: desc}, where: {deleted_at: {_is_null: true}, created_at: {_gt: "2021-06-16T10:06:38.551984+00:00"}, 
job_category: {slug: {_eq: $category}}, 
location: {slug: {_eq: $location}}, 
job_type: {slug: {_eq: $type}}}, limit: $limit)
```

Now if $category, $location or $type is empty, its not returning me the correct result.

Its actually returning me an empty array.

If I remove this:

```
job_category: {slug: {_eq: $category}}, 
location: {slug: {_eq: $location}}, 
job_type: {slug: {_eq: $type}}}, limit: $limit)
```

It works fine.

Can someone tell where am I going wrong?

Comment: which answer @joseglego

Comment: prepare and pass entire `where` object - don't glue it in graphql, no conditional syntax for that